# is it possible to route traffic to vpc endpoint using prefixlist

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i am trying to add a route using terraform

```
route {
    destination_prefix_list_id = "pl-XXXX"
    vpc_endpoint_id = "vpce-XXXXXX" //s3 
  }
```

but i am getting the below error

> Error: creating Route in Route Table (rtb-XXXXX) with destination (pl-XXXXX): InvalidParameterValue: Cannot create or replace a prefix list route targeting a VPC Endpoint.

FYI-- we already have one such route present in one of our route table which was created without terraform
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, one, this is not a reproducible example, so hard to tell really. If you want the same route, then you could try importing it, but as mentioned there is too little information to say.